# Hide row in table based on td cell in another row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here's the table:

```
<tr>
 <td id="test123" align="center" rowspan="6" style="padding-right:50px;padding-left:20px;">test123</td>
 <td rowspan="6">
 <td rowspan="6">
 <td rowspan="6">
 <td rowspan="4" style="display: none;">
 <td colspan="9">
</tr>
<tr> <---- HIDE THIS ROW
```

I know how to select the id=test123 and how to hide rows using .parent and jQuery, but how do you hide something below the selector you're using?

Comment: `$("#test123").parent().next()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method.

```
$("tr:has('#test123')").next().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#test123').parent('tr').next().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#test123').closest('tr').next().hide();
```